# Self Referencing List Custom Updateable Order

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I've defined the following domain:

```
class Module  implements Comparable<Module> {

    String name
    Integer displayOrder

    List<Module> subModules
    Set<ModuleItem> items

    static belongsTo = [parent: Module]
    static hasMany = [subModules: Module, items: ModuleItem]

    static constraints = {
        parent nullable: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        version false
        sort 'displayOrder'
        subModules joinTable: false, column: 'parent_id', lazy: false, sort: 'displayOrder'
        items lazy: false, sort: 'displayOrder'
    }

    @Override
    int compareTo(Module other) {
        this.displayOrder <=> other.displayOrder
    }
}
```

When I get a module with submodules, (even the first level), they are sorted by their sub_modules_idx rather than the displayOrder.

I've tried various way of resolving this, including criteria but can't seem to get the subModules back in any order other than sub_modules_idx.

How do I get the subModules back in displayOrder order?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can find for my use case is to apply a sort after we fetch the module.

i.e.:

```
 Module.list().each { module ->
     module.subModules = module.subModules.sort {it.displayOrder}
 }
```

If anyone can suggest a better solution, I'll accept their answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
subModules joinTable: false, column: 'parent_id', lazy: false, sort: 'displayOrder', order: 'desc'
```

you can use 'asc' depending upon your need

Comment: 'asc' is default if none is provided, and ascending display order is as I require.  I'll try 'desc' to see if this does apply the sort on displayOrder.